# How virtual CPUs are mapped to physical cores?

Tags: linux, multithreading, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

I am writing a computationally intense multithreaded program in Java that will run in in a virtualized environment and I wander how "Number of CPU" setting on the guest OS will affect the performance of my program.

Essentially the question is how guest OS CPUs are mapped to host CPU cores? Suppose I set CPU count on guest OS to one even though I run on quad core machine, what does it really mean? I can speculate that at least one of two scenarios happening:

1. My single virtual core gets bound to a particular physical one and so guest is essentially running on a single core.
2. There is no hard-binding/allocation of virtual CPU to physical core. And so any time any process on guest OS needs to start a new thread it can be dispatched to **any** physical core for execution: any one of four, as in my example.

The latter case would mean that the guest OS is running in multi-core environment even though it "thinks" it has a single core. (By "think" I mean that the command like cat /proc/cpuinfo reports back only one core)

I am asking question in general, but if there are idiosyncratic differences between for example VirtualBox and VMWare in that area, and you happen to know them, I would appreciate you sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what would happen in most cases is somewhere in the middle, as long as you are using hardware-based [system-level virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_virtualization) and not something like [User-mode Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux).

As far as the host OS is concerned, the VM would only have one CPU thread per virtual core. There might be other threads for I/O etc, but those are independent of the virtual core count, being part of the emulator and completely invisible to the guest OS.

The end result is that on a single-core VM all guest threads would run on the same CPU at each specific moment - guest threads are "batched" together in a container thread and are not individually visible to the host OS.

That said, unless you set the [CPU affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) of the emulator thread to one or more specific physical CPU core, the host OS scheduler may periodically migrate the thread to a different core every few seconds, much like any other process.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think the virtual CPUs correspond to the maximum number of threads that a virtual machine can have running on the host at any given time.